# user created during ubuntu 22.04 install in virtualbox can't use sudo

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox, sudo

New to Ubuntu and "sudo" command.I've successfully installed 22.04.2 on Virtualbox. During the install it asked for a user and password which I entered. After logging into the Ubuntu desktop with user created, using sudo to update system asks for password, then fails with 'user is not in sudoers' file. What do I do from here? I can't update the system or install anything.
Thanks.

Comment: I followed the answer here {link}(https://askubuntu.com/a/1462530/1715833). Couldn't get to a repair or rescue shell.

Comment: What was the exact command you used to attempt to update the system? Show this and the error message. Please edit your question with this and any new info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add myself back as a sudo user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70442/how-do-i-add-myself-back-as-a-sudo-user)